# How to define min or max to determine the minimum value between tow numbers or in array?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I have recently defined a code for a problem in CPLEX and I have encountered a syntax error when I wanted to get the minimum value in an array. please see the code provided below as an example.

```
float Y = min (2.3, 3, 4, 2, 13, 45)
```

I got this error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use minl

```
float Y = minl (2.3, 3, 4, 2, 13, 45);

execute
{
  writeln(Y);
}
```

gives

```
2
```